# Post correspondence problem: Busy beaver variant

Tags: reference-request, computability-theory, decidability

The Post correspondence problem ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem)) is to decide for $k$ pairs of strings $$(a_1,b_1), (a_2, b_2), ..., (a_k,b_k),$$ if there exists a finite sequence of numbers $c_j, 0\le j\le j_\max $ such that $$a_{c_1}a_{c_2}...a_{c_{j_\max}}=b_{c_1}b_{c_2}...b_{c_{j_\max}}.$$ The decision problem is undecidable.

Which led me to the idea of constructing a Busy beaver ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver)) analogue. Let a set of pairs be called solvable if a positive solution exists in that case, and the minimum length of a particular solvable set of pairs of strings to be the smallest possible value of $j_\max $ of a solution. Then $PCP(k, m, n)$ is defined to be the largest minimal length of all solvable sets of k pairs of strings over an alphabet of size m, with no string having length longer than n. Since there is a finite list this function is well defined.

It seems trivial to show that if $PCP(k,m,0)=1$, and . Also $PCP(1,m,n)=1$ (either $a_1=b_1$ or it's unsolvable)

$PCP(k,m,1)=2$ for $k\ge 2$, because the only possibilities for the first pair used are ('a','a') (which would solve in length one), or ('a',''), and ('','a') (and those last two must match for there to be a solution).

Has this function been studied before? Are small values known? It seems, though appearances could potentially be deceiving, that values of this function might be easier to find than the Busy Beaver Problem for similar values (though obviously as a whole the function is uncomputable). Under what constraints is the function computable (e.g. $n\le 2$)?

https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6700 shows that for $k\ge 4, m\ge 2$, the decision problem is undecidable, and hence the function is uncomputable for general n.

Edit: I realized the empty string can be used, so $PCP(k,m,1) $ is not necessarily equal to 1. $PCP(k,m,0)=1$ trivially though.

Comment: If n is fixed, then as k increases PCP(k,m,n) should stabilize, as there is only a finite number of possible pairs...
As a variant, one can perhaps define PCP( M; n), where one instead looks at all possible sets of pairs, but the total number of symbols (in alphabet of size n) used in the pairs is at most M. Then PCP(M,2) would be an interesting sequence for OEIS - perhaps one can compute a few of the first entries...

Comment: True, I never thought about that, but as there are only finitely many possible pairs for a given M and n, so it would eventually stabilize, at least by k=M^2n